# Objects of a specific type in foreach from an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, generics, foreach, ienumerable

I'm working with a legacy collection object that only implements non-generic `IEnumerable` and `ICollection`. What exactly happens with this object when I try to use this object with a `foreach` giving a more specific type on the LHS of the foreach expression?

```
// LegacyFooCollection implements non-generic IEnumerable
LegacyFooCollection collection = GetFooCollection();
foreach (Foo f in collection)
{
    // etc.
}
```

I know (because I've tried it) that this is safe when everything in `collection` really is of type `Foo`, but what happens if that fails?

Comment: I thought it would be null in that case.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The C# compiler performs the cast implicitly for you. In terms of the casting (but *only* in those terms<sup>1</sup>) it's equivalent to:

```
foreach (object tmp in collection)
{
    Foo f = (Foo) tmp;
    ...
}
```

Note that this will happen with generic collections too:

```
List<object> list = new List<object> { "hello", "there", 12345 };

// This will go bang on the last element
foreach (string x in list) 
{
}
```

This is all detailed in section 8.8.4 of the C# 4 spec.

If you're using .NET 3.5 or higher and you want to only select items of the appropriate type, you can use [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
LegacyFooCollection collection = GetFooCollection();
foreach (Foo f in collection.OfType<Foo>())
{
    // etc.
}
```

That may not be necessary for a `LegacyFooCollection`, but it can be useful when you're trying to find (say) all the `TextBox` controls in a form.

---

<sup>1</sup> The differences are:

- In your original code, `f` is read-only; in the "conversion" it's writable
- In your original code, if you capture `f` you will (currently) capture a single variable across all iterations, as opposed to a separate variable per iteration in the "conversion"

Comment: No, actually, it's not equivalent to that.  First, the syntax is `foreach (object tmp in collection)`.  Second, you can assign whatever you want to `f` in your example, while you cannot do so in the OP's example, since his `f` is a foreach iteration variable.  (A subtle, but important difference.)

Comment: @cdhowie: Yes, I meant to include the part about the read-onliness. There's also a difference if the variable is captured. Fixed the typo of "=" for "in" (which was pretty obviously just a typo - feel free to just edit such things in future).

Answer (score 4):

This code will create a runtime type conversion (cast) of each element of the enumerable to `Foo`.  So, if you did `foreach (string f in collection)` you would get a `ClassCastException` at runtime, the first time it tries to convert a `Foo` reference to a `String` reference.

Answer (score 0):

It will be casting each time. The `foreach` loop is just using the `IEnumerator` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Short cast in ForEeach:

```
foreach (MenuItem menuItem in treeView.ContextMenu.Items.Cast<object>().OfType<MenuItem>()
{
    // Do stuff
}
```