# InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type. (Unity c# ,foreach list loop)

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, foreach

Hi I am having a problem with this code.

It throws an

> InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

when trying to access the WeaponClass-objects in inventory:

```
public static List<ItemsClass> EquiptWeapon(EquipablesClass o, List<ItemsClass> inventory)

{//This function recive a item class (o) and a List


    if (o is WeaponsClass)
    {
        //This line here is the problematic one (InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.)
        foreach (WeaponsClass z in inventory) {
           //This loop is made so if i already have a weapons equipped this will unequipped
           z.IsEquipted = false;
        }

       //Then i equip the weapon that was passed
        o.IsEquipted = true;

       //The player class has a weapon class in it, so now i assign it. So i can ask directly to the player class when i need the info
        WeaponsClass y = o as WeaponsClass;

        Player.player.WeaponEquip = y;

    }
    return inventory;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objects of a specific type in foreach from an IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165730/objects-of-a-specific-type-in-foreach-from-an-ienumerable)

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure every item in `List<ItemsClass> inventory` is of type `WeaponsClass`, then you can do this:

```
foreach (var item in inventory.Cast<WeaponsClass>())
{
    //...
}
```

Please note if there is even one item which cannot be casted to `WeaponClass`, you will get an exception. The other approach you can take is:

```
foreach (var item in inventory)
{
    var casted = item as WeaponClass; // No exception if cast fails, simply returns null
    if(casted != null)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The other approach you can take is:

```
foreach (var item in inventory.OfType<WeaponsClass>())
{
    //...
}
```

and the documentation for it is pretty clear:

> Filters the elements of an System.Collections.IEnumerable based on a specified type.